# Javascript audio onClick won't play

Tags: javascript, audio

I was making an game from a course project using html, css and javascript, and in this game i need to kill a fly everytime i click on it, so i decided to use an audio for everytime the fly dies to make the game more fun, the rest of the function is ok but my audio is not playing, altough i'm getting the audio source right.

`

```
fly.addEventListener("click", function(){
    this.remove()
    points += 10
    document.getElementById('hasPoints').innerHTML = points
    console.log(sound)
    sound.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
        sound.play()
    })
})
```

`

i've also already tried to add the sound preload property to auto but it still didn't work

Comment: Try to move your "canplaythrough" listener at the top of your fonction.

Comment: Still didn't work, the rest of the function is working fine, but the audio just won't play

Answer (score 0):

The only solution i could achieve was changing how the sound would function, instead from playing everytime i kill a fly, i made it play for every click on the window, using window.addEventListener